# Character encoding i.e. \u00a9 is not getting preserved while reading and writing JSON file in java

Tags: java, json, unicode

I got a problem while reading and writing json file using JSON simple library in java.

I am reading and updating json file which contains few unicode characters i.e. \u00a9, \u03A8 etc. using Java code. After writing gets completed when I open the file, the unicode charcters given above get replaced with some garbage values i.e. Î¨Ñ¬Î­Ó¬Û’ÕœÝœ even though I am opening and writing json file with "UTF-8" encoding.

Below is the java code i used for reading and writing json file.

```
//Open for Reading
File fr = new File(filepath);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fr),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

//Writing file
File file = new File(filepath);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Can someone please help me out how i can retain charcter encoding?

Comment: *"when I open the file"* How do you open the file?

Comment: I open the file in notepad++ editor to see that the update is successful in json file. When i observe other portion of file i.e. Unicode characters they got changed automatically to garbage valye eventough I have not touched that portion.

Comment: Can someone look into this at earliest, as I need to submit the solution as soon as possible to fix one urgent regression issue?

Comment: Open both the before file and the after file in NotePad++, and verify that the Encoding pull-down menu says UTF-8.

Comment: I already did that and made sure that it has encoding set to UTF-8. But still facing the same issue. I am not sure how the contect got changed eventhough I have not touched it.

Comment: `Î¨` is Windows-1252 for UTF-8 bytes `CE A8`, which is `\u03A8` (`Ψ`). So, at some point, the UTF-8 text is read as Windows-1252 / ISO-8859-1. You should debug your code and see what Java is reading.